# What does the caret symbol do in a Rails validation error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
class Person
  validates_numericality_of :identity_id, :message => "^Person field definition id must be an integer"
end
```

Now, what is the effect of using the `^` in the message property?

Answer (score 6):

When you want to override the error message without the attribute name, simply prepend the message with `^` like

```
validates_numericality_of :identity_id, :message => "^Person field definition id must be an integer"
```

gives

> Person field definition id must be an integer

instead of

> Identidy Id Person field definition id must be an integer